# Problems with Indexing by Latent Semantic Analysis

Tags: python, indexing, crash

Whenever I try to run this python script, in Windows 7 Enterprise (64 bit) with python 2.6.6 installed, I keep getting this error

> Problem signature:
>     Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
>     Application Name: python.exe
>     Application Version:  0.0.0.0
>     Application Timestamp:    4c73f7b6
>     Fault Module Name:    _csr.pyd
>     Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
>     Fault Module Timestamp:   4d6a645b
>     Exception Code:   c0000005
>     Exception Offset: 000c05d4

I've tried re-installing python and all the modules that my program runs on (ie gensim, nlptk, scipy and numpy)

I don't know if this is enough data for you guys, but please let me know!!

```
lsi = models.LsiModel(corpus, num_topics = num_Topics)
index_lsi = similarities.MatrixSimilarity(lsi[corpus])

for k, v in dict_Queries.items():
        File.write("Check Key: " +k+ "\n")
        print "Running.... \n" 
        vec_bow = dict.doc2bow(v.split(), allow_update=True)
```

---

```
#In the last iteration, the code below the line doesn't run and i think the vec_lsi  
#is the source of the problem but I don't know why?
        vec_lsi = lsi[vec_bow]

        #indexing the LSI
        sims = index_lsi[vec_lsi]
        sims = sorted(enumerate(sims), key = lambda item: -item[1])

        if not cut_Off == 0:
            sims = sims[0:cut_Off]
        else:
            pass

        for t in sims:

            dup_info = dict_tcs.get(t[0])

            if t[1] > 0.75:
                #print "Key: " + k + " Link: " + dup_info + "\n"
                File.write("Adding: "+str(t)+ " To LSI actual \n")
                if dict_Actual_LSI.has_key(k):
                    links = dict_Actual_LSI.get(k)
                    links.append(dup_info)
                else:
                    links = []
                    links.append(dup_info)
                    dict_Actual_LSI[k] = links
        print "Added\n"
```

In the last iteration, the code below the line doesn't run and i think the vec_lsi is the source of the problem but I don't know why?

Thanks

Comment: Does anything work?  Does `print "hello world"` work?

Comment: Exactly- for example, try `python -c "print 'hello, world'"` in the command line

Comment: Yes that works, so is it something inside my code?

Comment: Yes. Just to be clear: How are you running your program? Are you running it from the command line? In that case, you should get an exception with a traceback.

Comment: I am running it from the command line but no traceback appears on the prompt.... it only flags me with a external screen displaying the error above

Answer (score 3):

Exception code c0000005 means "access violation". This generally means that some piece of code tried to read from or write to a memory address that it didn't have permission to access. This might be due to a corrupted pointer, uninitialized memory or native code indexing out of the bounds of an array.

The module that the fault is in is _csr.pyd. This is a part of SciPy that sounds like it's for manipulating sparse arrays. This would suggest that the error is happening because somehow SciPy has been pointed towards invalid memory. Without seeing your program it's hard to guess how this might have happened.

As a next step, you could try to pin down what's happening immediately before the crash by adding some print statements to your program - by printing out its progress you can narrow down where the crash is occurring. If you're lucky it might then become clear why SciPy is trying to access invalid memory.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't show my entire code, for a bunch of reasons, but like you said this could more be a bug with SciPy than my code?

Comment: It's possible it's a bug in SciPy, but it could equally be a bug in gensim, or even in your own code, depending on how you feed input to gensim and what guarantees it makes. Your best bet for solving this will be to reduce your program and data to the smallest size you can still produce the crash and then provide the reduced code and data to the SciPy or gensim developers.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the advice, the code is very similar to both what is outlined on the gensim website and previous methods that have worked for me, so I will relay my problems to them.